# Responsive navigation open by default

Tags: jquery, html

I'm working an HTML page and I created a responsive navigation menu. It works fine with one exception. When I resize my browser and the normal navigation switches to the responsive pull-down menu, the menu is open by default. I'd like it to be closed by default and only open when a user clicks on the menu button.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="main-nav" id="navbarResponsive">
  <a href="#" id="pull"></a>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="respNav">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Blog </a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Features</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Invest</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and here is my jquery code:

```
$(function() {
  var pull    = $('#pull');
  menu    = $('.main-nav ul');
  menuHeight  = menu.height();

  $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      menu.slideToggle();
  });
});

$(window).resize(function(){
  var w = $(window).width();
  if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
    menu.removeAttr('style');
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you try add a class named `open` at the nav bar you have, and once the page is loaded, just do something like `menu.classList.add('open")`

Answer (score 0):

Please add it in your css file accordion to resolution of device,

```
.main-nav .navbar-nav{
   display : none;
}
```